# Javascript plugins in Ajax website

Tags: javascript, ajax, dynamic, plugins, gallery

I'm currently using an ajax plugin called Ajaxify so that I can load a page content dynamically.

Everything is working fine, plain content and images get's loaded, but not javascript plugins like galleria. 
The plugin only loads if I go to the page directly.

So if I go for instance to: test.com/gallery - it loads.
If I go to test.com and then click on gallery via the navbar, the plugin doesn't load.

In the div where the content has to be loaded with ajax, I have applied the following script:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://derrickson.nl/wp-content/themes/derrickson/js/theme.js"></script>

<div id="gallery">
<div id="galleria"></div>
</div>
<div id="menu">
    <a href="http://flickr.com/photos/davidhellsing/sets/72057594078378762/">Test1</a>
    <a href="http://flickr.com/photos/davidhellsing/sets/72057594102602315/">Test2</a>

 </div>
<a id="fullscreen" href="#">Enter fullscreen</a> 


<script src="http://derrickson.nl/wp-content/themes/derrickson/js/theme.js"></script>
```

Ajaxify plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajaxify-wordpress-site/
galleria plugin:http://galleria.io

Ajaxify script:

```
    /* <![CDATA[ */
var aws_data = {"rootUrl":"http:\/\/derrickson.nl\/","ids":"#pull   a","container_id":"guts","mcdc":"nav-top","searchID":"searchform","loader":"ajax-loader.gif"};
/* ]]> */




(function(window,undefined){

// Prepare our Variables
var
    History = window.History,
    $ = window.jQuery,
    document = window.document;

// Check to see if History.js is enabled for our Browser
if ( !History.enabled ) return false;

// Wait for Document
$(function(){
    // Prepare Variables
    var
        // Application Specific Variables 
        rootUrl = aws_data['rootUrl'],
        contentSelector = '#' + aws_data['container_id'],
        $content = $(contentSelector),
        contentNode = $content.get(0),
        // Application Generic Variables 
        $body = $(document.body),
        scrollOptions = {
            duration: 800,
            easing:'swing'
        };

    // Ensure Content
    if ( $content.length === 0 ) $content = $body;

    // Internal Helper
    $.expr[':'].internal = function(obj, index, meta, stack){
        // Prepare
        var
            $this = $(obj),
            url = $this.attr('href')||'',
            isInternalLink;

        // Check link
        isInternalLink = url.substring(0,rootUrl.length) === rootUrl || url.indexOf(':') === -1;

        // Ignore or Keep
        return isInternalLink;
    };

    // HTML Helper
    var documentHtml = function(html){
        // Prepare
        var result = String(html).replace(/<\!DOCTYPE[^>]*>/i, '')
                                 .replace(/<(html|head|body|title|script)([\s\>])/gi,'<div id="document-$1"$2')
                                 .replace(/<\/(html|head|body|title|script)\>/gi,'</div>');
        // Return
        return result;
    };

    // Ajaxify Helper
    $.fn.ajaxify = function(){
        // Prepare
        var $this = $(this);

        // Ajaxify
        $this.find('a:internal:not(.no-ajaxy,[href^="#"],[href*="wp-login"],[href*="wp-admin"])').live('click', function(event){
            // Prepare
            var
                $this   = $(this),
                url     = $this.attr('href'),
                title   = $this.attr('title') || null;

            // Continue as normal for cmd clicks etc
            if ( event.which == 2 || event.metaKey ) return true;

            // Ajaxify this link
            History.pushState(null,title,url);
            event.preventDefault();
            return false;
        });
        // Chain
        return $this;
    };

    // Ajaxify our Internal Links
    $body.ajaxify();

    // Hook into State Changes
    $(window).bind('statechange',function(){
        // Prepare Variables
        var
        State       = History.getState(),
        url         = State.url,
        relativeUrl = url.replace(rootUrl,'');

        // Set Loading
        $body.addClass('loading');

        // Start Fade Out
        // Animating to opacity to 0 still keeps the element's height intact
        // Which prevents that annoying pop bang issue when loading in new content


        if( '' != aws_data['loader']) {
            $content
                    .html('<img src="' + rootUrl + 'wp-content/plugins/ajaxify-wordpress-site/images/' + aws_data['loader'] + '" />')
                    .css('text-align', 'center');
        }

        // Ajax Request the Traditional Page
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                // Prepare
                var
                    $data           = $(documentHtml(data)),
                    $dataBody       = $data.find('#document-body:first ' + contentSelector),
                    bodyClasses     = $data.find('#document-body:first').attr('class'),
                    contentHtml, $scripts;

                var $menu_list = $data.find('.' + aws_data['mcdc']);

                //Add classes to body
                jQuery('body').attr('class', bodyClasses);

                // Fetch the scripts
                $scripts = $dataBody.find('#document-script');
                if ( $scripts.length ) $scripts.detach();

                // Fetch the content
                contentHtml = $dataBody.html()||$data.html();

                if ( !contentHtml ) {
                    document.location.href = url;
                    return false;
                }

                // Update the content
                $content.stop(true,true);
                $content.html(contentHtml)
                        .ajaxify()
                        .css('text-align', '')
                        .animate({opacity: 1, visibility: "visible"});

                //Scroll to the top of ajax container
                /*
                jQuery('html, body').animate({
                            scrollTop: jQuery(contentSelector).offset().top
                            }, 1000);
                */

                //Append new menu HTML to provided classs
                $('.' + aws_data['mcdc']).html($menu_list.html());

                //Adding no-ajaxy class to a tags present under ids provided
                $(aws_data['ids']).each(function(){
                    jQuery(this).addClass('no-ajaxy');
                });

                // Update the title
                document.title = $data.find('#document-title:first').text();
                try {
                    document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = document.title.replace('<','&lt;').replace('>','&gt;').replace(' & ',' &amp; ');
                }
                catch ( Exception ) { }

                // Add the scripts
                $scripts.each(function(){
                    var $script = $(this), 
                        scriptText = $script.html(), 
                        scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
                    try {
                        // doesn't work on ie...
                        scriptNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(scriptText));
                        contentNode.appendChild(scriptNode);
                    } catch(e) {
                        // IE has funky script nodes
                        scriptNode.text = scriptText;
                        contentNode.appendChild(scriptNode);
                    }
                    if($(this).attr('src') != null) {
                        scriptNode.setAttribute('src', ($(this).attr('src')));
                    }
                });

                $body.removeClass('loading');

                // Inform Google Analytics of the change
                if ( typeof window.pageTracker !== 'undefined' ) window.pageTracker._trackPageview(relativeUrl);

                // Inform ReInvigorate of a state change
                if ( typeof window.reinvigorate !== 'undefined' && typeof window.reinvigorate.ajax_track !== 'undefined' )
                    reinvigorate.ajax_track(url);// ^ we use the full url here as that is what reinvigorate supports
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                document.location.href = url;
                return false;
            }

        }); // end ajax

    }); // end onStateChange

}); // end onDomLoad

})(window); // end closure

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

//Adding no-ajaxy class to a tags present under ids provided
jQuery(aws_data['ids']).each(function(){
    jQuery(this).addClass('no-ajaxy');
});

//append anchor tag to DOM to make the search in site ajaxify.
var searchButtonHtml = '<span id="ajax-search" style="display:none;"><a href=""></a></span>'
jQuery("body").prepend(searchButtonHtml);

//Make the link ajaxify.
jQuery("#ajax-search").ajaxify();

//After submitting the search form search the post without refresing the browser.
jQuery("#" + aws_data['searchID']).live('submit',
    function(d){
        d.preventDefault();
        var host = aws_data['rootUrl'] + "?s=";
        jQuery("#ajax-search a").attr("href", host + jQuery(this).find("#s").val());
        jQuery("#ajax-search a").trigger("click");
    }
);
});
```

Comment: can you post your javascript code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to load your plugin in ajax call so you need [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)

so put this code in your callback of ajax call:

```
$.getScript('your galleria plugin url');
```

Comment: put this line in the callback of your ajax call

Comment: could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I have had great luck with [http://headjs.com/](http://headjs.com) - very flexible.